# Given many examples of a text, classify some never before seen text

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a bunch of example texts for specific labels. Using this data, I want to be able to classify a new piece of text for the lable.

I have a dozen to a hundred of rows of data like this:

```
Product Description | Price | Batteries | Reviews

The HP notebook is a bargain...., $200, Included, 37
Acer just released a new laptop...., $500, Not Included, 0
Lenovo Thinkpad is hitting the market .., $800, None, 23
```

and then for a new text like this, I want to be able to pull out the labels.

```
Samsung Ultrabook is sleek and new..., $900, n/a, 2 reviews
```

I've looked at the python library Spacy's rule based matching, but I'm not sure how to recognize a chunk of text like the product description. The price, reviews are fairly easy to define rules for but it's not clear for the product description as the length is all over the place. However, from the 100s of rows there exists a minimum and maximum, and I was thinking of training some sort of neural network that will be able to detect a given text and classify it.

The core question is, how do I teach a neural network many examples of a label, and then detect it on some new corpus?

update: this is the output I expect for (the order is unpredictable and may contain more items than below)

`Samsung Ultrabook is sleek and new..., $900, n/a, 2 reviews`

so I will loop over each item and it should identify the one of the labels `['product description', 'price', 'batteries', 'reviews']`. If no label is found from the input, it is ignored.

Comment: What classifications are you hoping to retrieve from this list of examples?

Comment: @usr2564301 basically i want to classify a given column as either Product Description, Price, Batteries, or Reviews. The other columns are easy as they are small and have predictable ranges. Detecting a product description is the main problem for me.

Comment: I am not 100% on what you understand as "classify". With your short sample text, all it needs is splitting on commas. Even if there might be commas in the descriptive text, a regex can locate the dollar amount and then everything before it is "product decription".

Comment: Please post the desired output of your classificator...

Comment: @Anakin87 updated with output

Comment: @usr2564301 the commas are not present and i cant predict what text i will receive. i simply provide a list of strings and the classifier must predict what labels to apply based on what it has seen.

Answer (score 1):

You need text classification model to perform this, lets say you want to classify given description into one of label :

For Training:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

vectorizerPipe = Pipeline([
                     ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',lowercase=True,ngram_range = (1,3),min_df=2,max_df=0.95,sublinear_tf=True)),
                     ('classification', LinearSVC(penalty='l2',loss='hinge')),
                ])
    model=vectorizerPipe.fit(df.loc[:,'product description'], df.loc[:,'label'])
    print('Training done')
```

For Testing :

```
model.predict(['Acer just released a new laptop...'])
```

You can change parameters of TfidfVectorizer and LinearSVC as per your need.

Comment: what does the `:,` mean in the panda dataframe `df.loc[:,'product description']` ?

Comment: also what is the `'df.loc[:,'labels']` supposed to represent? sorry not familiar with panda dataframes.

Comment: im also getting the error:     `('classification', LinearSVC(penalty='l2',loss='hinge'),n_jobs=-1)
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: 1) :, means slicing (select all roes from column product description) 2) df. Loc[:, 'labels'] means column which you want to predict. 3) for syntax error i wil check and correct the answer

Comment: I have edited my code now this should work.. And if it satisfies your question please upvote